# Replace the selected text and add a link in draft js

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I know how to add a link to the selected text but I need to replace the selected text value and add a hyperlink to it in draft js

**eg** If i have written  " Go to Google " in the editor of draft js and if I select Google and want to replace Google with Yahoo and then add a link to it .

I know how to add a link If i select the google

```
 const contentState = this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent();
    const contentStateWithEntity = contentState.createEntity(
        'LINK',
        'MUTABLE',
        {url: "https://google.com"}
      );
      const entityKey = contentStateWithEntity.getLastCreatedEntityKey();
      const newEditorState = EditorState.set(this.state.editorState, { currentContent: contentStateWithEntity });
      this.setState({
        editorState: RichUtils.toggleLink(
          newEditorState,
          newEditorState.getSelection(),
          entityKey
        )})
```

But I need to replace the text value of Google also and add a link to it

Comment: Spend some time explaining your problem. Show some code

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I have explained the question Can you check